# How to compute the correlation between a vector and each column of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Hey I am having a little bit of missunderstanding and need a little bit of guidance. I want to compute the correlation between a vector (or df with 1 column) and each line of a dataframe.

I made a graphic for a better understanding:
!(https://ibb.co/51Fk5KB)

All rows have a date and fit to a unique `as.Date` of the other dataframe. Because I want to compute it in a rolling window of 12 months I run:

```
df1 <- read.zoo(df1)
df2 <- read.zoo(df2)
new_df <- rollapplyr(??????????, 12, function(x) cor(x[, 1], x[, 2]), by.column = TRUE, fill = NA)
new_df <- fortify.zoo(new_df)
```

Now I ask you: what do I have to insert in the ***??????????*** spot? Or do I even have to change/add something else?

Answer (score 4):

You can use calculate the correlation between a vector and columns of a dataframe like so `cor(vector, dataframe)`

#### Example

Create a vector and dataframe :

```r
set.seed(1234)
vec <- (runif(150, 0, 10))

iris2 <- iris[,c(1:4)] # 150 x 4 dataframe
```

Now calculate correlations

```r
cor(vec, iris2)

# Correlations
# -0.0187099581910839078691 -0.0233219261874525844724 -0.0063229780212239634907  0.0138003706052788940178
```

Comment: `cor(vec, iris2)` is nicer. You get the df column names.

Comment: @RuiBarradas your idea is so much more elegant.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have updated the answer as `sapply` was not required

Comment: You could have kept yours, to know two ways of doing the same is not a bad idea. Specially since the OP believed `rollapply*` was needed.

Comment: I deleted my comment. Your answer does really not help me getting a solution.

Comment: @JeremyS. I read the first lines of your question (including diagram) and thought I knew what you wanted. I see you want a rolling period. If you can provide a dataframe, vector, and desired output in your question, I'm sure it can be solved (try using `dput()` to allow us to quickly reproduce the dataframe/vector/output